# Test Selector Plugin Jenkins returns No tests were executed

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run a simple test with the Tests Selector Plugin for Jenkins. I followed the [tutorial in the wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tests+Selector+Plugin).

When I am going to build, I get this tree (which looks ok)
[image: Tests Selector Tree]

My config file is this one:

```
tests=[{"enabled":true,"owner":"saul","testgroup":"A","testcase":"NewTest.testJenkinsWebsite"},{"enabled":true,"owner":"saul","testgroup":"B","testcase":"NewTest.testJenkinsWebsiteAgain"}]
enableField=enabled
groupBy=testgroup
fieldSeparator=.
showFields=testsuite,testcase
multiplicityField=multiplicity
```

And my test class is this:

```
public class NewTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Usual Code here
    }

    @Test
    public void testJenkinsWebsite() throws Exception {
        // Some test here
    }

    @Test
    public void testJenkinsWebsiteAgain() throws Exception {
        // Other test here
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I press "Build" I get the following error:

```
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.858s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 08 17:44:27 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/41M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project SampleSeleniumGrid: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: since your properties file is basically copied from the tutorial, and I can't find any obvious glaring errors .... what did you enter into the multiplicity field? what did you choose as environment variable?

Comment: Surefire 2.10 is old; I think the current version is something like 2.18.  Maybe updating version would help.

Comment: Vogel612 You were correct!! It was the environment variable. I had only "test" instead of "tests" as I wrote in the properties file. Now the project compiles, but it is always compiling all the tests even If I unselect them from the menu. What can be wrong there?